# How to optimize size of WiX Bootstrapper size?

Tags: wix, burn

I have a CustomBA in my WiX Bootstrapper.

The CustomBA library is 500KB.

The Chain refers to two ExePackages (188 MB + 202 MB) and one MsiPackage (934 MB).

**The Bootstrapper Exe is 798 MB**

1. Why is the Bootstrapper Exe so big?
2. Does it contain the ExePackages or MsiPackage?
3. How can I optimize the size?

Answer (score 0):

By setting Compressed to "No" in the Bundle and then using post build events in the ExePackages and MsiPackage the size of the Bootstrapper itself can be kep to a minimum.